# How do I post a single value to PHP MyAdmin. This code doesn't seem to work. I am trying to get a value from a form into a database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

```
<form action="signup.php" method="POST" id="newsletter">
<h4>Join Our Newsletter</h4>
<input id="email" type="text" value="Enter Email Address Here For Updates" onBlur="javascript:if(this.value==''){this.value=this.defaultValue;}" onFocus="javascript:if(this.value==this.defaultValue){this.value='';}">
<input type="submit" value="Sign up" class="btn2">
</form>


<?php

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=test_db";
$DBusername = "test";
$DBpassword = "test";

try {
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $DBusername, $DBpassword);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {

}

$email = $_POST["email"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (email) VALUES (:email)";

$pdoQuery = $conn->prepare($sql);

$pdoQuery->bindValue(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$pdoQuery->execute();

setcookie("success", "You have successfully signed up for the newsletter.", 0, "/");

header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

These are both on separate pages, and I can't seem to figure out why they won't work.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Nothing posts to the database at all.  The cookie is working though.

Comment: Your text input needs a `name` attribute. Like `name="email"`.

Comment: _Note:_ PHPMyAdmin is just a web based management tool for the database MySQL. Unless you're doing something in that web tool directly, you're not working with PHPMyAdmin, but with MySQL.

Comment: @cteski I did just try that, but unfortunately I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: "Doesn't work" should be your first observation. Next step is trying to figure out why, and often that means inspecting all available sources of data. `var_dump($_POST)` could've helped here. Eliminate possible sources of problems. Also check your Network Inspector in the browser to be sure that the values are being encoded and sent as expected with the right names. Also check error logs, as PDO can throw exceptions on errors.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Alright, thanks for the information.  I will take note of that when asking questions in the future.

Comment: That's not propper connection string. Where is the `host` part? [http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: Why do you have an empty `catch` when looking for problems?

Comment: @borked97 you said you will take note of it for the future, but you _should_ take note of it _now_ and update your question accordingly so we can actually give you some real advice instead of guessing what the issue is and possibly providing bad information.

Answer (score 2):

Your connection is probably failing.  You don't have a host in your DSN

```
 $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test_db";
```

Not sure if it is localhost, but hope this shows what it should be.  It would also probably help that when you catch the exception, that you output something.

even...

```
catch(PDOException $e) {
     echo "error - ".$e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
     exit;
}
```

Comment: I'm not hosting the database.  It's one provided by my university.  This should work, as it's the same thing I've done in the past with the same database.  I'll keep working toward finding a solution.  Thanks for your input though, it's incredibly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately still not working, hmm.  Hopefully I'll figure this out